# Ignore https gcloud composer airflow

Tags: airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I am running a gcloud composer command from behind a proxy how do I set it to ignore https.

```sh
gcloud composer environments run $project --location $location list_dags
```

**Unable to connect to the server: x509: cannot validate certificate for X.X.X.X because it doesn't contain any IP SANs**

Comment: Thats not the same command, this is "gcloud composer"

Comment: I think the proper way to solve this problem should be configuring the certificate. As you can see here in this explanation SSL should not be disabled https://serverfault.com/questions/611120/failed-tls-handshake-does-not-contain-any-ip-sans

Answer (score 1):

Up to current versions of Cloud Composer (1.9.0 at the time of writing), the `gcloud composer environments run` command works by connecting to the Kubernetes master of your environment's GKE cluster. The error means there is something is potentially wrong with the configuration given to you by the GKE API, or there is something intercepting your traffic (like a non-transparent proxy on a corporate network). You should verify that you can connect to the Kubernetes master using `kubectl` and resolve any issues with that before trying to use the Composer command.

To connect using `kubectl`, obtain cluster credentials and then try issuing a few commands:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone=$Z $COMPOSER_CLUSTER_NAME
kubectl get pods
```

To answer your question directly, you can use `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` can fix your issue if you use `kubectl`, but this option cannot be passed to `gcloud composer`.